# Android: How to share images from package directory?

Tags: android, file-sharing

I want to share multiple image from application package directory. My files locate in following path as like. `/data/data/com.example`. Now i can get images path. But not attach any images to sharing application. as like whats app, Message and Facebook etc. I have implemented permition in manifest file. See below my try.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(saveList.get(0).toString())));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Here are some files.");
            intent.setType("image/*"); /* This example is sharing jpeg images. */
            ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            for(String path : saveList /* List of the files you want to send */) {
                File file = new File(path);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                files.add(uri);
            }

            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Implemented permission is below.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Search around a bit, this has been answered before. You'll need to implement a `ContentProvider` to give any other app access to files in your private folder.

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30172585/1944896

Answer (score 1):

It is compatible with scoped storage. So don't need any storage permission.

```
fun shareFile(){
    var intentBuilder: ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
    intentBuilder = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
        .setType("image/jpg")
    intentBuilder.addStream(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this.baseContext!!
        , getString(R.string.package), File(path)))
    val intent = intentBuilder.intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send to "))
}
```

In Manifest

```
 <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Create a xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <files-path path="/" name="allfiles" />
  <external-path path="/" name="externalfiles" />
  <root-path name="external_files" path="/storage/" />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `Uri.fromFile()` will not work in your case, because third-party apps have no access to your [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Second, using a `file:` `Uri`, such as from `Uri.fromFile()`, appears as though [it will be banned in the next version of Android](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).

Instead, you need to use [some sort of `ContentProvider`, such as `FileProvider`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/16/how-publish-files-via-content-uri.html), to make the files available to third-party apps. This is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html).

Comment: @RaviVaghela: [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) shows using `FileProvider`, albeit for `ACTION_VIEW`, not `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: my question is i want to share image from application package folder like `/data/data/com.example/image/image1.jpg` this type. I am store image in package folder i need it for share image i can show in imageview but not share. @CommonsWare

Comment: @RaviVaghela: That is not a standard location; `FileProvider` will not support it. You will need to write your own streaming `ContentProvider`, or switch to storing your files in a more conventional spot (e.g., `getFilesDir()`) that `FileProvider` supports.

Comment: yes that for i have to copy data in external storege and share it

Comment: @RaviVaghela: That will not help you starting with the next version of Android, as [Google starts banning `file:` `Uri` values](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107129/discussion-between-ravi-vaghela-and-commonsware).