# Clear App Cache: Where to put files that should get deleted?

Tags: android, caching

I have an App where Users can download PDF's and Videos and store them locally, so that they dont need to download it later again. These PDF's and Videos only need to be accessable from within the App. What i mean by that is, that only the App can **find** those files but they can then be opened by third party apps (so that i dont need to implement pdf reader and video player specially for my app).
I would call an intent to the third party app with the path to the file.

The User should be able to delete all these files from within the App Settings but also when the User uses the devices app settings to clear app cache.

So clearing the app cache in android device settings should also delete those downloaded PDF's and Videos.

**Is there an ellegant way to do this?**

**Does it make sense to use a `FileProvider` or does the `FileProvider` does not get touched by the android device settings clear cache?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the different storage options available in Android from the following link:

[Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

You could use getCacheDir() or getExternalCacheDir() to get the directory where you could store the file.

However you will not be able to share the files in cache directly with other apps using intent.

In order to share the file in cache directory you will have to implement FileProvider.
You can find more information from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096275/share-image-file-from-cache-directory-via-intentandroid).

This will achieve both your objective i.e the files will be cleared when app is uninstalled plus you would be able to share the files in cache with other 3rd party apps.